# How do I get duplicated ips when there is more than 1 reservation that is not duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to get duplicated `ip_number` records when there are different `reservation_id`.

```
DECLARE @Reservations TABLE (ip_number INT, reservation_id VARCHAR(16), name VARCHAR(16),quote_date DATETIME, arrival_date DATETIME, deposit_amount DECIMAL(16,2)

INSERT INTO @Reservations (ip_number, reservation_id, name, quote_date, arrival_date, deposit_amount)
VALUES 
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132518,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','64.20'),
  (50053177,21132518,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','64.20'),
  (50053177,21132714,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','32.10'),
  (50053161,21131464,'Amy','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','52.31'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50039951,21125684,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125683,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125683,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125682,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125682,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88');
```

I am currently trying to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rth.ip_number DESC) AS row, 
       reservation_id,
       name,
       ip_number,
       quote_date,
       arrival_date,
       deposit_amount
FROM r_order_reservation
WHERE quote_date > '2022-12-01';
```

This returns the following:

```
row reservation_id  name        quote_date              arrival_date             deposit_amount
1801    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1802    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1803    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1804    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1805    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1806    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1807    21132518    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  64.20
1808    21132518    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  64.20
1809    21132714    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  32.10
1810    21131464    Amy         2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-28 07:00:00.000  52.31
1811    21131445    Chung       2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-28 07:00:00.000  119.04
1812    21131445    Chung       2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-28 07:00:00.000  119.04
1813    21131445    Chung       2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-28 07:00:00.000  119.04
1814    21125684    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-31 07:00:00.000  103.88
1815    21125683    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-30 07:00:00.000  103.88
1816    21125683    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-30 07:00:00.000  103.88
1817    21125682    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 07:00:00.000  103.88
1818    21125682    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 07:00:00.000  103.88
```

Christine has 3 `reservation_id` `21132003`,`21132518` and `21132714`, but its showing the duplicated records for `reservation_id`  `21132003` and `21132518`.

Amy has only 1 `reservation_id` `21131464`.

Chung has multiple `reservation_id` `21131445` that are the same, but do not include any other `reservation_id`.

Jennifer has 3 different `reservation_id` `21125684`,`21125683` and `21125682` but has a duplicated `reservation_id` of `21125682`.

I am trying to pull in records that have different `reservation_id` but have the same `name`,`quote_date`,`arrival_date` and `deposit_amount`when there is more than 1 `reservation_id` made by the same `ip_number` on a given `quote_date`.

Expected Results:

```
row reservation_id  name        quote_date              arrival_date             deposit_amount
1801    21132003    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  288.90
1802    21132518    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  64.20
1803    21132714    Christine   2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 00:00:00.000  32.10
1804    21125684    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-31 07:00:00.000  103.88
1815    21125683    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-30 07:00:00.000  103.88
1817    21125682    Jennifer    2022-12-27 00:00:00.000 2022-12-29 07:00:00.000  103.88
```

Comment: I hope you're not relying on IP address for anything important. IP address is notoriously unreliable as an identifier.

Comment: Are reservations really duplicated or might you be mistake on joins ? Can you add example data to work on it?

Comment: @SunBrnt I am still not able to understand what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how a row_number helps you de-dupe here or if this data is your actual table or the result of a (potentially flawed?) query - but perhaps this is what you are after?

First identify the those groups with more than one `reservation_id` and then join this with the data set and selecting distinct rows:

```
with d as (
    select name,quote_date,arrival_date, Count(distinct reservation_id) dupe
    from Reservations 
    group by name,quote_date,arrival_date
)
select distinct *
from Reservations r
where exists (
    select *
    from d
    where d.name = r.name
    and d.quote_date = r.quote_date
    and d.arrival_date = r.arrival_date
    and d.dupe > 1
);
```

[Demo FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OL_YaFbw)

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you expect to be like ?

```
DECLARE @Reservations TABLE (ip_number INT, reservation_id VARCHAR(16), name VARCHAR(16),quote_date DATETIME, arrival_date DATETIME, deposit_amount DECIMAL(16,2))

INSERT INTO @Reservations (ip_number, reservation_id, name, quote_date, arrival_date, deposit_amount)
VALUES 
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132003,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','288.90'),
  (50053177,21132518,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','64.20'),
  (50053177,21132518,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','64.20'),
  (50053177,21132714,'Christine','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','32.10'),
  (50053161,21131464,'Amy','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','52.31'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50053151,21131445,'Chung','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-28 07:00:00.000','119.04'),
  (50039951,21125684,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125683,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125683,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125682,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88'),
  (50039951,21125682,'Jennifer','2022-12-27 00:00:00.000','2022-12-29 07:00:00.000','103.88');

WITH TMP AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ip_number DESC) AS row,
        reservation_id,
        name,
        ip_number,
        quote_date,
        arrival_date,
        deposit_amount
    FROM @Reservations
    WHERE quote_date > '2022-12-01'
    GROUP BY reservation_id, name, ip_number, quote_date, arrival_date, deposit_amount
)
SELECT *
FROM TMP T1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TMP T2
    WHERE T1.name = T2.name
        AND T1.ip_number = T2.ip_number
        AND T1.quote_date = T2.quote_date
        AND T1.arrival_date = T2.arrival_date
    GROUP BY T2.name, T2.ip_number, T2.quote_date, T2.arrival_date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```